# Check if a value is contained in an array and return the results

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have `array = ["Michael","Abraham", "Gabriel","Festus", "Ahab"]` how can I return elements in the array containing `myValue = "ab"` which should be (Abraham,Gabriel,Ahab), I understand "indexOf" checks for the complete match.

Comment: What you have done so far ? hint: use `filter` and `includes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the filter method of array, please reference the code snippet below:

```js
const array = ["Michael","Abigail","Gabriel","Festus", "Ahab"]
console.log(array.filter((name) => name.indexOf("ab") > -1));
```